# Closing other activity and opening a new one by pressing a button: Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to close an activity while opening another one by pressing a button on Android Studio I've tried this:

```
public void MainActivity(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    (FirstActivity(MainActivity();)).finish();

}
```

This code was written in FirstActivity.java in my project. But not worked, unfortunately.

Is there any other way of doing or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks for the helpers out there!

Necessary information:

**FirstActivity.java**

```
    package com.ardacebi.libra;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    }



    public void MainActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);



    }



}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.ardacebi.libra;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Activity_First.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ardacebi.libra.FirstActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/libralogo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to Libra"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The file sharing platform"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Libra, let's you to share your files over a private, secured network to your friends easily"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Sharing"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="MainActivity"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note: I want to send the user to the MainActivity when the Start Sharing button pressed on the FirstActivity.**

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Grbe.png)

Comment: Can you post logcat?

Comment: Is this code in the "MainActivity" class?

Comment: Can say what are the activities you have and what do you want this code to do with these activities.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Added necessary information to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the main activity from the first activity, it should be like this :

```
public void MainActivity(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

**Tip1** : You don't need to finish the first activity if you want the user to back to it, so if you finish the main activity that we just created or the back button pressed, it will just go back yo the first activity without needing to create a new one.

If you want to open the main activity and finish the first one, just add "finish();" after starting the main activity like this:

```
public void MainActivity(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

**Tip2** : In this case you need to start another first activity, you can't go back to the same first activity because we finished it.

Hope My Answer Was Useful To You :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped. Take care!

Comment: One more question Mousa, how can I change the launch screen after the begin sharing button is pressed. So the app can remember that the user has already passed the welcome screen and automatically launch the Main Activity? You can edit your answer and add an extra part at the bottom. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, this is can be done, and I will post another answer, because that answer needs another section.

Comment: Ok, I will be waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the app remember that the user pressed the sharing button using :**SharedPreferences**
In the public class of the first activity add this line which is basically the name of the Preferences :

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PreferencesFile";
```

On the **onCreate** method of the first activity add the code :

```
//Get the value of the "FirstBun" key.
SharedPreferences Settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean FirstRun = Settings.getBoolean("FirstRun", true);

if(FirstRun == false){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

When pressing the sharing button add this code :

```
public void MainActivity(View v){
    //Change the value of "FirstRun" key to 'False' before opening the main activity.
    SharedPreferences Settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", false);
    editor.apply();

    //Open the main activity.
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

**Note** : the Preferences is a 'xml' file stored with the files of the app.

If you cleared the data of the app in the AppInfo of the app in the Android device, the value of the "FirstRun" key will return to the default which is 'true'.

Comment: Giving error, can't resolve SharedPreferences and getBoolean. How can I fix that?

Comment: You have to import this under the package name of your app : import android.content.SharedPreferences;

Comment: Still not, it's giving the same error. I'm going to give you a GitHub Repository link that you can see later I'm still working on it. Is that a good idea for you?

Comment: Yes sure, i will try to do that.